# How to pass data to child server components without prop drilling and using context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13, react-server-components

> React Server Components allow us to write UI that can be rendered and optionally cached on the server.

It's great, but it turns out that we can't use context with them.

Therefore my question - let's suppose I want to fetch some JSON from API on Next.js page level and then propagate the data to vast hierarchy of child components.

How can I do it without polluting it with prop drilling? I can't use context - it's client only:

> You're importing a component that needs createContext. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

I can't use state management library as well - also client only...

What is clean solution for server components?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time thinking about this and finally came up with a solution using the new React cache API (which means the data is only cached/shared across a given request received by our server, which is usually what we want).

I created a library, [rsc-better-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsc-better-cache) to make it easy to use.

Let me know what you think of it.

Here's how to use it:

```js
// mySharedData.ts
import { createCachedPromiseGetter } from 'rsc-better-cache';

interface MyData {
  someProp: string;
}

export const myDataPromiseGetter = createCachedPromiseGetter<MyData>();
```

```js
// MyReactServerComponent.tsx (React Server Component where the data is obtained)
import { myDataPromiseGetter } from './mySharedData';

const MyReactServerComponent = async (params) => {
  const myData = await fetch(`some-url/${params.id}`);
  myDataPromiseGetter().resolve(myData);
}
```

```js
// MyOtherReactServerComponent.tsx (React Server Component lower (or higher !) in your app tree)
import { myDataPromiseGetter } from './mySharedData';

const MyOtherReactServerComponent = async () => {
  const myData = await myDataPromiseGetter();
}
```